# Como enviar uma mensagem de erro para o usuário de Forma correta?

Tags: php

Olá Sou estudante de **PHP** e gostaria de saber de vocês mais experientes o seguinte, se mandar a mensagem de erro para o usuário através de uma `$_SESSION` e após essa mensagem ter sido "visualizada" a sessão ser destruída, seria uma boa prática. e se não for, de que maneiras posso fazer isso?

**Meu Exemplo:**

*Simulação de login:*

```
 else{
    //2.1- se der erro no passo anterior mostrar o erro
    //criar uma sessão para mandar a mensagem na index
    $_SESSION['erro'] ='Preencha os campos Corretamente!';
    header('location:index.php');
    }
```

Agora esta é a página que recebe a mensagem:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['erro'])) {
  echo "<div class='card-panel yellow darken-4'>".$_SESSION['erro']."</div>";
  session_destroy();
}?>
```

Comment: A forma que você fez , atende a essa situação específica , mas pense na possibilidade de voce trabalhar com outros erros no seu sistema, após o usuário logado. Ou na possibilidade de você usar a sessão pra salvar outras coisas. , é recomendável você excluir apenas o que não está utilizando na variável , você pode utilizar o comando unset($_SESSION['erro'])que destruirá apenas essa variável específica.

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi, então no caso, se o  usuário já estiver logado no sistema, eu também posso utilizar a  `$_SESSION['erro']` para mandar outras mensagens, no entanto como poderei reutilizá-la em outras instâncias ao invés de destruí-la, posso apenas "esvaziá-la" usando o `unset()` ..